# Error on serialization due to circular dependency

Tags: c#, datacontractserializer, datacontract, csla, datacontractsurrogate

I have a custom base class `Entity` decorated with `[DataContract(IsReference = true)]` and deriving from `UndoableBase` of [CSLA.net](http://cslanet.com/). Keeping IsReference is important to preserve object reference data.

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public abstract class Entity : UndoableBase
```

I am getting exception upon serialization using below code snippet:

```
public void SerializeToFile(string fileName, T obj)
{
    _serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
    Serialize(fileName, obj);
}

private void Serialize(string fileName, T obj)
{
    using (var fs = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Create))
    {
        _serializer.WriteObject(fs, obj);
        fs.Close();
    }
}
```

> **System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException**
>
> The IsReference setting for type 'Entity' is 'True', but the same
>   setting for its parent class 'Csla.Core.UndoableBase' is 'False'.
>   Derived types must have the same value for IsReference as the base
>   type. Change the setting on type 'Entity' to 'False', or on type
>   'Csla.Core.UndoableBase' to 'True', or do not set IsReference
>   explicitly.

If I remove this IsReference attribute altogether I start getting following error:

> Object graph for type 'XYZ' contains cycles and cannot be serialized
>   if reference tracking is disabled.

Now my question is how to solve it by changing the `IsReference` setting for `Csla.Core.UndoableBase` during serialization using some API.

While researching on this topic I came across this post, which talks about using `DataContractSurrogate`. Please help how to use it specifically if it is helpful in this case or suggest any other technique solving it.

[How to serialize class that derives from class decorated with DataContract(IsReference=true)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282761/how-to-serialize-class-that-derives-from-class-decorated-with-datacontractisref)

Comment: I am not sure if DataContractSurrogate will help you here. What exactly is causing the circular reference in your graph: have you identified this? In my experience, sometime the circular reference is not even needed.

Comment: You are right but in my case circular dependency do exists because I have a type where I am preserving parent-child relation by exposing Parent property of the same type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After quite a struggle I was finally able to find the answer to this question. There is an overloaded constructor which takes `preserveObjectReferences` flag to instruct the serializer to preserve the References. In my case, I have now removed `IsReference` annotation from all over and used below overload for serialization and life is good.

```
var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T), knownTypes,
            int.MaxValue /*maxObjectsInGraph*/,
            false /*ignoreExtensionDataObject*/,
            true /*preserveObjectReferences*/,
            null /*dataContractSurrogate*/);
```

Reference: [Preserving Object Reference in WCF](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sowmy/2006/03/26/preserving-object-reference-in-wcf/)